# Pass in string as argument without it being treated as raw

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to pass in a string to my python script which contains escape sequences such as: `\x00` or `\t`, and spaces.
However when I pass in my string as:

```
some string\x00 more \tstring
```

python treats my string as a raw string and when I print that string from inside the script, it prints the string literally and it does not treat the `\` as an escape sequence.
i.e. it prints exactly the string above.

**UPDATE:(AGAIN)**
I'm using *python 2.7.5* to reproduce, create a script, lets call it `myscript.py`:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

now save it and call it from the windows command prompt as such:

```
c:\Python27\python.exe myscript.py "abcd \x00 abcd"
```

the result I get is:

```
> 'abcd \x00 abcd'
```

P.S in my actual script, I am using option parser, but both have the same effect. Maybe there is a parameter I can set for option parser to handle escape sequences?

Comment: Are you literally `print`ing it, or are you just looking at the return value of your function in a console?

Comment: yeah becuase in IDLE i do `print "some string\x00 more \tstring"` and it works just fine

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example of your function? (You can try cutting out everything not related)

Comment: no Im passing it in as an argument. so c:\MyScript.py "abc\x00abc". then inside the script I print args[0], and I get abc\x00abc as my output

Comment: does print(args[0].decode('string-escape')) solve the issue? edited based on your edit.

Comment: Yes, you want John Faulkner's `decode()` method. John, you should post that as an answer!

Comment: @kindall it did not work for me

Comment: @JohnFaulkner it did work! but I had to do s = sys.argv[1]   s.decode('string-escape'). for some reason it doesnt like sys.srgv[1].decode()

Comment: myscript.py contains:

    import sys
    print(sys.argv[1].decode('string-escape'))

result
    abcd   abcd

Comment: @JohnFaulkner Please put in your solution as an answer to this issue so you can get credit :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string you receive in `sys.argv[1]` is exactly what you typed on the command line. Its backslash sequences are left intact, not interpreted.

To interpret them, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python): basically use `.decode('string_escape')`.

Answer (score 6):

myscript.py contains:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1].decode('string-escape'))
```

result
    abcd   abcd

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you can parse entire strings without writing a custom parser but optparse supports [sending inputs in different formats](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#standard-option-types) (hexidecimal, binary, etc).

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-n", type="int", dest="num")

options, args = parser.parse_args()

print options
```

then when you run

```
C:\Users\John\Desktop\script.py -n 0b10
```

you get an output of

```
{'num': 2}
```

The reason I say you'll have to impletement a custom parser to make this work is because it isn't Python the changes the input but rather it is [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994827/how-to-read-argv-value-without-escape-the-string) [the shell does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590838/python-escape-special-characters-in-sys-argv). Python might have a built in module to handle this but I am not aware of it if it exists.

Comment: ok you are the first to understand my problem. This is the right track, but my issue is I need tp pass in a long string that contains \x00 in a few spots. I dont want to pass in the whole string as int values.